# Is it Possible to use a pre-trained model without fine-tuning it?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I’m curious about how to use the pre-trained model version without fine-tuning because I want to compare the results of the fine-tuned version with those of the non-fine-tuned model.

For information, I’m fine-tuning the Wav2Vec2 XLS-R model.